# Simpler OnClickListener?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, anonymous

i am new and learning , i have checked many related posts but still my few following questions are unanswered...[Edited ]the language is java...

following is the way to handle the click on button but can any one explain

- 1, why i have to declare the anonymous class ,
- 2, how i know that i have to declare the anonymous class here or any where else could ?
- 3, why i cannot use simple the btn.setOnClickListener();  why i must have to call anonymous class here ... below line is simple to do the task ...!!

  btn.setOnClickListener();

why to make two more lines of code ...? i.e

```
@override public void onClick (View v) {....}
```

======================

```
Button btnCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCountId);
btnCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) { ...... }
});
```

Comment: apologies i edited its java language...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Java entity called an "`interface`".

`View.setOnClickListener` accepts an object of type "`OnClickListener`". So you first need to create an object of such a type.

The Object `OnClickListener` is indeed an `interface` with one function "`onClick`", so to create an object of that type you need to implement it (define all the functions in the interface) - in this case, only one.

```
OnClickListener myClickListener=new OnClickListener() {
   @Override // override means you are implementing a function in the interface or a derived class
   public void OnClick(View v) {
        // the button has been pressed
   }
};
```

and then you can assign it to a view:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```

or to many views:

```
myButton1.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
myButton2.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
myButton3.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```

In Java you'll find objects use listener interfaces to communicate events. 
Mind that more complex objects use interfaces **that can have several methods** instead of just one, that's when the simplification you see is not that handy.

Imagine an object "`Girl`" that has a method "`flirt`" that you can invoke to ask her for dinner. The Girl will take some time to decide, then communicate one of a lot possible answers with the same interface.

```
OnGirlFlirtListener  myGirlFlirtListener=new OnGirlFlirtListener() {

   @Override
   public void onGirlSaidYes() {
       // invite the girl to have dinner
   }

   @Override
   public void onGirlSaidNo() {
       // find another girl or hang with your mates instead
   }
   @Override
   public void onGirlSaidMaybe() {
       // ask her later
   }
   @Override
   public void onParentsHateMe() {
       // forget about that girl
   }

}
```

Then you can do:

```
mGirl.flirt (myGirlFlirtListener);
```

And the code is indeed elegant: With one interface you control all the possible answers! It's the same for a lot of objects in java (and Android).

Instead of creating the listener as an object, and setting it, you can as well create it as an anonymous class if you won't reuse it, of course.

### EDIT

How to create a generic clicklistener?

Sometimes, in the same dialog, you have 15 or 20 buttons that do more or less the same, and only differ in a detail. Although you can perfectly crete 20 clicklisteners, there's a cooler way taking advantage of `View.setTag()` function.

`setTag` allows you to store **whatever object you want to any view**. You use that do distinguish, inside a clicklistener, which button was pressed.

So imagine you have 5 buttons: Brian, Peter, Loise, Krasty and Sue:

```
mButtonPeter.setTag("Peter Griffin");
mButtonLouise.setTag("Louise Griffin");
mButtonBrian.setTag("Brian");
mButtonKrasty.setTag("Krasty");
mButtonSue.setTag("Sue");

OnClickListener personClickListener=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void OnClick(View buttonPressed) {

       String person=(String)(buttonPressed.getTag());
       // you pressed button "person"
       Toast.makeText(buttonPressed.getContext(), "Hey, "+person+", how is it going!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   
};

mButtonPeter.setOnClickListener(personClickListener);
mButtonLouise.setOnClickListener(personClickListener);
mButtonBrian.setOnClickListener(personClickListener);
mButtonKrasty.setOnClickListener(personClickListener);
mButtonSue.setOnClickListener(personClickListener);
```

Isn't it cool?

Comment: thanks a lot , rupps ... so that means , its same concept of implementing the interface ( with all methods must implement ) but in my code its done by using anonymous class  how ever in your code its few more lines but its more clear for me like a new learner first implementing post creation of object ( clicklistener ) and then passing the click listener object to SetOnClick method....

Comment: yes that was the point of my answer, your abbreviation is totally valid, but this way you can better understand why it takes those more lines! And as you get more proficient in Android, you'll see sometimes it's very interesting to **reuse the same clicklistener**., that is, write a generic one and use it for 10 buttons. Look at the edit to see how cool this is.

Answer (score 0):

When you are "setting an onClickListener" what you are doing is telling: "when this button is clicked, execute this code".

The code to be executed is implemented in the provided annonymous function.

You can't simply do btn.setOnClickListener() without an argument because that would not provide the information regarding which behaviour to perform when the button is clicked.